# Can we brainstorm for an automated tagging system?

Tags: nlp

I am interested to do automatic tagging for bodies of text. I am pretty new to NLP so I would like to hear some methods which you guys are familiar with in this context.

Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of taggig are you doing? Entity tagging? Text classification? Part of speech tagging? Your question is two vague.

Answer (score 0):

bag-of-words approaches should work okay. you're just trying place one tag on the entire text, right?

however, as another member pointed out to me one time, StackOverflow is mostly a programming Q&A.